# How to insert data from auto generated and already created data

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have One table that does not have primary key and foreign key table name is **C_User_Credentials** I have attached screen shot please go through for more details 
[image]

and i have written one stored procedure code is

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Duplicate]
      @inputkey NVARCHAR(36)
    , @Formkey NVARCHAR(36) output
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Form NVARCHAR(36)
    SET @Form = NEWID()

    SELECT *
    INTO #s
    FROM [2290_Form]
    WHERE PK_2290F_key = @inputkey

    INSERT INTO [2290_Form]
    VALUES (@Form, (SELECT #s.FK_C_B_key FROM #s), (SELECT #s.is_vin_correction FROM #s), (SELECT #s.is_amendment FROM #s), (SELECT #s.amendment_category FROM #s), (SELECT #s.is_final_return FROM #s), (SELECT #s.first_used_month FROM #s), (SELECT DATEPART(year, GETDATE()) FROM #s), (SELECT #s.tax_amt FROM #s), (SELECT #s.additional_amt FROM #s), (SELECT #s.credit_amt FROM #s), (SELECT #s.payment_mode FROM #s), (SELECT #s.consent_tag FROM #s), (SELECT #s.status FROM #s), GETDATE(), NULL)

    SELECT NEWID() AS Pk
         , @Form AS fk
         , vin
         , category
         , is_logging
         , is_agricultural
         , is_mileage_exceed
         , weight_current
         , weight_old
         , credit_reason
         , buyer
         , effective_date
         , tax_amt
         , GETDATE() AS crn_dt
         , NULL AS upd_dt
    INTO #v
    FROM [2290_Vehicles]
    WHERE FK_2290_F_key = @inputkey

    INSERT INTO [2290_Vehicles] (PK_2290_V_key, FK_2290_F_key, vin, category, is_logging, is_agricultural, is_mileage_exceed, weight_current, weight_old, credit_reason, buyer, effective_date, tax_amt, crn_dt, upd_dt)
    SELECT * FROM #v

    SET @Formkey = @Form


END
```

In above stored procedure one form key will generate.problem is with the help of generate form key I need to merge **CFK_C_UP_key** column from C_User_Credentials table and **generated form_key** both in one new table How to do please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea what you are trying to do here but your procedure is way over complicated. You do not need to create temp tables to hold data so you can just turn around and insert it into another table right afterwards. Also, you have defined your guid columns as nvarchar(36). This requires an implicit conversion. If they really are guids you should use the correct datatype.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Duplicate]
      @inputkey NVARCHAR(36)
    , @Formkey NVARCHAR(36) output
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Form NVARCHAR(36)
    SET @Form = NEWID()

     INSERT INTO [2290_Form]
     select @Form
        , FK_C_B_key
        , is_vin_correction
        , is_amendment
        , amendment_category
        , is_final_return
        , first_used_month
        , DATEPART(year, GETDATE())
        , tax_amt
        , additional_amt
        , credit_amt
        , payment_mode
        , consent_tag
        , status
        , GETDATE()
        ,NULL
    from [2290_Form]
    WHERE PK_2290F_key = @inputkey

    INSERT INTO [2290_Vehicles]
    (
        PK_2290_V_key
        , FK_2290_F_key
        , vin
        , category
        , is_logging
        , is_agricultural
        , is_mileage_exceed
        , weight_current
        , weight_old
        , credit_reason
        , buyer
        , effective_date
        , tax_amt
        , crn_dt
        , upd_dt
    )

    SELECT NEWID() AS Pk
         , @Form AS fk
         , vin
         , category
         , is_logging
         , is_agricultural
         , is_mileage_exceed
         , weight_current
         , weight_old
         , credit_reason
         , buyer
         , effective_date
         , tax_amt
         , GETDATE() AS crn_dt
         , NULL AS upd_dt
    FROM [2290_Vehicles]
    WHERE FK_2290_F_key = @inputkey
END
```